# Can I use Proto DataStore and Preference DataStore at the same time?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

I have recently migrated Preference DataStore into Proto DataStore. I see where it has advantage, but now I need to store a single `String` type into DataStore, and making a separate proto for this doesn't seem worth it.

Obviously it's just making a single file and compiler will do most of the work, but is there a disadvantage of using Proto and Preference DataStore at the same time? If I need to store a single value like this, I'd use Preference, and for other structured types, I'd use Proto.

Thank you.